# Непонятно как присвоить 0 пользователю который заходил не в текущем месяце

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Делаю запрос на количество посещений в месяц вот так:

```
SELECT dbo.Пользователи.[ID пользователя], COUNT(dbo.Посещения.[Дата посещения]) AS [Количество посещений за месяц]
FROM dbo.Пользователи 
INNER JOIN dbo.Посещения ON dbo.Пользователи.[ID пользователя] = dbo.Посещения.[ID пользователя] AND dbo.Посещения.[Дата посещения] >= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
GROUP BY dbo.Пользователи.[ID пользователя]
```

Проблема в том, что не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы пользователь, который не заходил в этом месяце, то есть
**COUNT(dbo.Посещения.[Дата посещения]) = 0**

Буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 1):

Вероятней всего надо заменить **INNER JOIN** на **LEFT JOIN**

Но это не точно.

Comment: Спасибо помогол, не могли бы вы сказать, почему так?

Comment: Читайте в документации в чем разница между LEFT и INNER. В общем-то это частый вопрос на собеседованиях - пригодится. А если просто и "на пальцах" - то в случае INNER в выборку попадают только те записи из связываемых таблиц, между которыми есть связь. В случе же LEFT в выборку обязательно попадают все записи из одной таблицы, и только связанные с ними записи из второй таблицы.